# Page Source is not Updated when a menu item is clicked in Appium Java Android Testing

Tags: java, android, selenium, appium

I am new to Appium Java Testing. So, far I am able to log in the android application.

the android application has a menu when is clicked via Appium Java Code. The screen corresponding to the click is updated but the PageSource XML is not. So far, I am not able to access anything on the page.

I am using APPIUM JAVA vers 6 Beta 3
Selenium version 3.9.1
and Nexus 6P android version 7.1.1.

the source via UIautomator is attached in the screen shot. Some how, the page is not able to update with a new view but it is stuck on the old view. 
Please help me in understanding the issue.
I am giving the exception Element Not Found

Stack Trace:

> {appActivity: ...., appPackage: , databaseEnabled: false, desired: {appActivity: ...., appPackage: , deviceName: Nexus 6, noReset: true, platformName: android, platformVersion: 7.1.1, udid: emulator-5554}, deviceManufacturer: Google, deviceModel: Android SDK built for x86, deviceName: emulator-5554, deviceScreenSize: 1440x2560, deviceUDID: emulator-5554, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: false, networkConnectionEnabled: true, noReset: true, platform: LINUX, platformName: LINUX, platformVersion: 7.1.1, takesScreenshot: true, udid: emulator-5554, warnings: {}, webStorageEnabled: false}
>   Session ID: d0cc7fe5-e6ce-49d3-b39f-b9cada13bc55
>   *** Element info: {Using=id, value=:id/imageButton_editProfile}
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.JsonHttpResponseCodec.reconstructValue(JsonHttpResponseCodec.java:40)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:80)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:44)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:160)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:371)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementById(RemoteWebDriver.java:417)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.By$ById.findElement(By.java:218)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:363)
>       at appiumDemo.AppiumTest.Login(AppiumTest.java:97)

[screenshot of uiautomator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93Ic9.png)

Comment: Please show us your code, or at least line 97 of the Login method in AppiumTest.java.  There's nothing in the dump above to show what locator you used.  Are you trying to access the text highlighted in the screenshot?

Comment: I am not able to access any of the elements in the attached screenshot. the Appium page source is stuck on the previous page's xml. Do you want to see its screenshot.

the code goes something like this:

Comment: List<MobileElement> list= driver.findElements(By.id("/design_menu_item_text"));
list.get(0).click();                                                                                                      driver.findElementById("/textView_changePasswordDescription");

so after clicking changepassword from main menu, i am not able to access any elements from the xml of the attached screenshot screen.

Answer (score 1):

Is this a correct description of the problem?

1. On the first screen you are able to click "/design_menu_item_text" and the next screen appears.
2. On that screen you try to click anything without success, eg "/textView_changePasswordDescription".

Is `driver.findElementById("/textView_changePasswordDescription");` the actual code? If so, it should be changed to `driver.findElementById("/nl.weintegrate.wealert.app:id/textView_changePasswordDescription");

Comment: I omitted the name space of the package due to privacy policy. Yes I have done as you said but it still is not visible in pagesource() XML

Comment: In the stacktrace you have {Using=id, value=:id/imageButton_editProfile}. Is it this one or "/textView_changePasswordDescription" you have on line 97 in AppiumTest.java?